# How to align navbar item to the right side (also in the data-toggle when minimizing)?

Tags: html, css, toggle, navbar

I want to create a navbar where the logout and contact button are on the right side.
In the mobile view the nav-items should be combined in a collapse toggle. This is my code so far:

Untitled


    
        
            HeadlineCompany
            
                Toggle navigation

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">All Items</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Topics</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[actual normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZQD0.png)

[actual mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAAof.png)

This is how it should look:

[as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ0FU.png)

Does anyone have a tip on how I can make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - add a `<div>` wrapper to the `<ul>` (towards the bottom of my pasted code).

Here is JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omartheman949/eykr71c4/

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">HeadlineCompany</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            All Items
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Topics</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div> <!-- ************ADD THIS DIV WRAPPER************ -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- ************ADD THIS DIV WRAPPER************ -->
    </div>
  </nav>
```